# Flutter build ios error Expected identifier RunnerVersionNumber on Runner_vers.c

Tags: xcode, flutter

When I run `flutter build ios` I'm facing the above error:

> error generated.
> /Users/user926689/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-emyehpjhqbfhbsc
> xayqxsyftfyix/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runn
> er.build/DerivedSources/Runner_vers.c:5:72: error: expected identifier
> const double RunnerVersionNumber **attribute** ((used)) = (double)29   .;

[image]

`flutter doctor` is just fine. Last time I had no problem to build my app for ios.

What is `RunnerVersionNumber`? Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Problem solved.

Mistakenly I have added **a white space** right after the build number on `Runner -> General -> Identity -> build`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Spent ages tracking down this issue, white space in the build number, really?? XCode devs just trim() please??

Comment: @WebkraftStudios Lol ur so right.... it's all about a dam trim()